Which Android configuration change do I need to ignore to prevent activity destruction/creation when system language changes?
My Vulkan-based game is based on NativeActivity and needs to avoid ALL activity destroy/recreate configuration changes because of the massive amount of load time it takes to do that. I currently have this defined for the activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
android:configChanges="colorMode|density|fontScale|fontWeightAdjustment|grammaticalGender|keyboard|keyboardHidden|layoutDirection|locale|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode">

But when the user changes system language my activity is destroyed and re-created. Is there some other (undocumented?) config change I need to declare? How do I prevent activity destruction/recreation for system language changes?

That would be locale.  I also wouldn't worry about it-  nobody ever changes locale.  Even if they're bilingual, they don't change the locale of the phone to swap languages-  they just change the keyboard language.  You're talking about a scenario that only a QA person would ever find.

I agree that users usually not change system locale, but since Android 13 there is the possibility to set app-specific locales, thus changing may happen if the app give the users a reason to change (may be a certain translation is so bad that users try a different language).

Still not a common enough occurence to actually worry about.  And if they do change it, they'll do so once.  And the perf hit when it happens will be ignorable.

Thanks. I even tried adding an override fun onConfigurationChanged() method but I never get a notification for locale, nor any of the other listed configuration change events.
